# How to redirect android app to new page after login

Tags: android

At the moment I have a login page that works, but when logged in correctly just displays a toast, I want to send the user to a new page that just displays 'Login successful'. Here is what I have so far:

```
package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText  username=null;
   private EditText  password=null;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   public void login(View view){
      if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
      password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }    
   else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
      counter--;
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      if(counter==0){
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

   }

}
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: create new intent startt activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used `Explicit Intent` for this like

```
 Intent I=new Intent(loginPage.this, HomePage.class);
 startActivity(I);
```

You must have `Activity` with name `HomePage` register in your `manifest.xml`

### Look at

@Resources

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html
- [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Explicit_Intents_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example

Comment: would Test.class be a new activity I create?

Comment: so HomePage would be the activity you're redirected to?

Comment: @user3478524 exactly. This `HomePage` you can replace with the name of your target-activity.

Comment: @user3478524 ya exactly. go to any tutorial link.

Comment: I created the activity to be sent to correctly, but when I add in     Intent I=new Intent(loginPage.this, HomePage.class);
 startActivity(I);

the app just fails after I enter login details

Answer (score 0):

You can start a activity Through Intent

`Intent I=new Intent(loginPage.this, NewPage.class);
 startActivity(I);`

By This way You will Move from LoginPage to NewPage